# Split Multidimensional Array to two

Tags: php, arrays

I have below array,

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [test] => 0
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [73] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [test1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [96] => 6
                            [116] => 0
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [73] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [test1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [96] => 6
                            [116] => 0
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I want to split array to two like

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [test] => 0
        )
);

Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [73] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [test1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [96] => 6
                            [116] => 0
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [73] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [test1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [96] => 6
                            [116] => 0
                        )

                )

        )

);
```

How to do it? Please help. I have tried array_slice and it split the array but generate warning like `Warning: array_slice() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given.`

Is it okay if generate warning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use [`array_shift`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) and all done

```
$new_arr = array_shift($your_current_array);

print_r($new_arr);
print_r($your_current_array);
```

Comment: Yeah but same thing happen overhere,Its remove first element from array but generate warning like Warning: array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, null. what is reason behind this and will it affect in dynamic case?

Comment: Its because you were passing an empty array so you need to check for the condition as `if(is_array($array) && count($array) > 0)`

Answer (score 1):

In this instance you could just [`array_shift`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) the first array out:

```
$array1 = array_shift($array);
```

After this your input array will only contain the remaining items (which is what you want).